# How to get requestCode from pending intent at the time of alarm in android

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, alarm, android-pendingintent

Is it possible to get requestCode at the time of intent either in Receiver class or Activity Class?

and this was my pending Intent

```
alarmMgr= (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastReceiver_Class.class);
                /*intent.putExtra("alarm_time_minutes", minutes);*/
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode, intent,requestCode);
                alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put `requestCode`as extra to your intent. Like following:

```
intent.putExtra("requestCode", requestCode);
```

Then you can get it in Activity class by:

```
int requestCode = received_intent.getExtras().getInt("requestCode");
```

Comment: but how come built-in android apps such as camera and gallery knows the request code that you pass? @Kerim

Comment: Why this approach works, it doesn't make any sense. The requestCode parameter would become redundant in the method `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`

Comment: actually the requestCode in PendingIntent.getBroadcast() makes sense and give you a new pending intent